# Trying to pass an array of objects as a prop, but react keeps reading it as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to render a table with data gotten after filtering through resources from an API and removing some unnecessary object keys but anytime I try to pass the array as a prop to my table component, I get an error saying "Objects are not valid as prop types".
my filter function

```
const handleFetch = (query) => {
    const search = Accountdetails?.filter(
      (data) => data.holderArpAccountNumber == query,
    );
    return search;
  };
```

My Array :

```
const data = handleFetch(accountNumber)?.map((item) => {
    return {
      check: <Checkbox />,
      id: 1,
      holderName: item.holderName,
      certificateNumber: item.certificateNumber,
      holderCompanyAccountNumber: item.holderArpAccountNumber,
      clientCompany: item.issuingCompanyName,
      shareVolume: item.volumeOfBonds,
    };
  });
```

Table component:

```
<Table headers={headers} body={data} />
```

table component:

```
function Table({ headers, body }) {
  return (
    <div className="preview_and_save">
      <div className="greenpole-header">Exported CSCS Advice File</div>
      <table cellSpacing={1} cellPadding={0} className={'tableGrid'}>
        <thead className={'tableHead'}>
          <tr>
            {headers.map((item, i) => {
              return <td key={i}>{item}</td>;
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className={'tableBody'}>
          <tr>
            {body.map((item, j) => (
              <td key={j}>{item}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

logging typeOf data gives an object, but logging Array.isArray(data) gives true

Comment: You said you have an array of objects: It's possible the error is happening with `<td>{item}</td>`. If `item` is an object then React won't like that very much. I'd try `<td>{JSON.stringify(item)}</td>` and see if that makes the error go away

Comment: When I tried that I got this error: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    |     property 'stateNode' -> object with constructor 'HTMLDivElement'
    --- property '__reactInternalInstance$xlmydflsawf' closes the circle

Comment: Yeah that can happen sometimes with certain objects, it means the object can't easily be JSONified. You can also try `<td>{item.toString()}</td>`...but keep in mind this isn't actually a full solution, it's just a way to help you see where the problem is. The point is, if `item` is an object, you can't just inline it to React. React expects a string at that point. What I'm getting at is that you might be looking in the wrong place. The problem might not be with your array, it might be with what you're doing inside the `map`.

Comment: You're right. It was a problem with the `map`. Since it was an array of objects, rather than doing `<td>{item}</td>`, I had to do `<td>{item.name}</td>`, e.t.c. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

`typeof []` will return `object` because in JavaScript the array is a special type of `object` where the keys are index numbers.
Try console logging `data` and see what's in it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was the result:   (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {check: {…}, id: 1, holderName: "Andrew Efurhievwe", certificateNumber: "1324354565656565", holderCompanyAccountNumber: "2111389645", …}
1: {check: {…}, id: 1, holderName: "Andrew Efurhievwe", certificateNumber: "1324354565656565", holderCompanyAccountNumber: "2111389645", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

I made an object cloner function; check it out

```js
//how this clone function works, it gets all the property names of an object and sets it as their values are.. the function recurse would be for objects with several layers.. the stringToFile function is something that I use to have an understanding of the linking going on(as in circular data).. and for where it sees objects equal to other objects.. it does the clone version of that
function clone(obj){
  if(typeof obj!="object"){const x=obj; return x}
  function stringToFile(m,files){var x=files
    if(!m||m==""){return(files)}var errort=0
    m=m.split('\\');m.forEach(a=>{if(x[a]){x=x[a]}else{errort=1}})
    if(x==files||errort){return(0)}return(x)
  }
  var newObj={}; if(obj instanceof Array){newObj=[]}
  var arr=[]; var arr1=[]; var newObj1=newObj
  function recurse(obj,newObj,string){
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((a,i)=>{const string1=string
      const x={[a]:Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,a)}
      if(typeof obj[a]=="object"&&obj[a]!=null){
        newObj[a]={}; if(obj[a] instanceof Array){newObj[a]=[]}
        if(!arr.includes(obj[a])){
          arr.push(obj[a]); if(string==""){string+=a}else{string+=`\\${a}`}
          arr1.push(string); recurse(obj[a],newObj[a],string)
        }
        else{newObj[a]=stringToFile(arr1[arr.indexOf(obj[a])],newObj1)}
        string=string1; return;
      }Object.defineProperties(newObj,x)
    })
  }recurse(obj,newObj,""); return newObj
}


//demonstration
var myObj={a:1,b:2,c:{d:3,e:{f:4}}}
myObj.f=myObj //to make it circular for demonstration
var clonedObj=clone(myObj)
console.log(clonedObj==myObj) //false
console.log(myObj.f==clonedObj.f) //false
clonedObj.a++; clonedObj.c.d++ //these add only in clone
console.log([clonedObj.a,clonedObj.c.d]) //2,4
console.log([myObj.a,myObj.c.d]) //1,3
console.log(myObj);console.log(clonedObj) //see the full differences yourself
```

Comment: you should use the spread operator introduce in javascript ES6

Comment: why though? i was just demonstrating how to read an object as a copy or as the pointer

Comment: because in production you won't use that code/demostration, will you? you will use spread operator, if not then you should use it

Comment: i understand what you mean.. i made a cloner